# RichFaces and facelets combination not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, facelets

I am using RichFaces and jsf 2.but when I moved to facelets some of
        the rich component doesnt works for me. I am using

- richfaces-api-3.3.4.Final.jar,
- richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.4.Final.jar,
- richfaces-ui-3.3.4.Final.jar.
- tomcat version is 7.0.23
- netbeans 7.3.1

I have configured the following details in web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

     <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
       <param-value>Development</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
    <param-name>
        facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE
    </param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>

   <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
    <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <!-- Making the RichFaces skin spread to standard HTML controls -->
 <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
    <param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>   

 <filter>
    <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
 </filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
  </session-config>
   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
  <application>
  <view-handler>org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler</view-handler>
  </application>

   index.xhtml

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
      <!-- 
      To change this template, choose Tools | Templates 
      and open the template in the editor. 
      --> 
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
   xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" 
   xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" 
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 

   <ui:composition>     
   <h:form id="studentFormId" binding="#{StudentDetail.initForm}"> 
        <rich:panel id="Student" > 
            <f:facet name="header"> 
                <h:outputText value="Student DOB" /> 
    <rich:calender/>
            </f:facet>
     </rich:panel>
     </h:form>
     </ui:composition>
     </html>
```

When I deploy after clean and build it shows the following error.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.
    config.ConfigureListener java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 

    CONFIGURATION FAILED! Must have aConstructor that takes in a ComponentConfig

at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:273)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:842)

Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Must have a Constructor that takes in a ComponentConfig at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:449) at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
... 43 more
Caused by: javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Must have a Constructor that takes in a ComponentConfig
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.<init> (AbstractTagLibrary.java:330)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary.addComponent(AbstractTagLibrary.java:558)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagLibraryImpl.putComponent(TagLibraryImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processComponent(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:588)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags       (FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:368)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321)
at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270)
at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:437)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:org.richfaces.taglib.AjaxValidatorHandler.<init> (javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentConfig)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.<init>(AbstractTagLibrary.java:328)

... 51 more
```

Can anybody find what mistake I have done here?

Comment: For Tomcat 7 and JSF 2 your version of RichFaces is too old. RichFaces 4.x is recommended for this combination. Try Tomcat 6 version with RichFaces 3.3 (from my experience it was successfully worked combination).

Comment: ok vasil currently i am using many components from RichFaces 3.3.4 if i move to Richfaces 4 then does it have all components like Rich faces 3.3.4 version?

Comment: Not really, some components like Google Map are missing. But migrated components work fine. Plus there are a few new components. Note: your code contains error - `rich:calender` is wrong syntax (RichFaces has calendar component). Not related to question: if you start new project then you can try PrimeFaces (it has more components and better support than RichFaces).

Answer (score 3):

RichFaces 3.x and JSF 2 works fine. I'm using JSF 2.2 and RichFaces 3.3.4.Final.

You need to disable built-in JSF 2 facelets and add dependency on old jsf-facelets 1.1.15  (as per https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFaces333andJSF20).

However, keep in mind that Mojarra has a [bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1269) when it looks for `DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER` instead of `javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER` as per specification.

Comment: I would never suggest to use an old faceletes version with new jsf versions. If you run into issues it is hard to find a fix.

Comment: I didn't suggest anything. @Santhanam had a problem and I posted a solution to his problem hoping that it would help him (despite the question is one month old) and other people who, like us, are forced to use this combination of libraries due to circumstances.

Comment: Thank you very much for  Kukeltje and  Art Fedorychak.currently i am moving to PrimeFaces.